# when trying to execute below query am getting below error "Invalid query" , i think the issue is wih the second execute query

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE abc as 

ret number;
msg varchar2(1000);
Begin
execute immediate 'truncate table OBSPROJ';
execute  immediate 'exec obsproj_full_rebuild(:ret,:msg)';

End abc;
```

When trying to execute below query it results in "Invalid query"

I think the issue is with the second execute query.

Comment: when i am trying execute below getting same error                                                                    ret number;
msg varchar2(1000);
execute  'exec obsproj_full_rebuild(:ret,:msg)';

Answer (score 2):

Please see below: Read comments inline.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc
AS
   ret   NUMBER;
   msg   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table OBSPROJ';
   --This is how you call a procedure inside a procedure.
   obsproj_full_rebuild(ret,msg); -- I guess your procedure accepts some values. .Here you are just passing the variables you declared.
END abc;
```

execution:

```
sql> exec abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: exec is neither SQL nor PL/SQL command - that's why you are getting the error. If you still want to use dynamic SQL to call your procedure, you can wrap it in PL/SQL block and bind ret and msg variables:

```
execute immediate 'begin obsproj_full_rebuild(:ret,:msg); end;' using ret, msg;
```

But in fact you don't have to use dynamic sql to execute this procedure. You can simply, well, call the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc AS
     ret NUMBER;
     msg VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table OBSPROJ';
     obsproj_full_rebuild(ret,msg);
END abc;
```